# Glrotate function not working with the other ones

Tags: opengl, visual-c++

I need to perform a simple rotation i dont where it went wrong
i want to perform a rotation about a arbitary point.along with reflection and translation,basically its a composite tranformation.

```
void drawRectangle(void)
{   
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glPushMatrix ();
glRotatef(75.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
glVertex3f(0.0,100.0,0.0);
glVertex3f(100.0,100.0,0.0);
glVertex3f(100.0,0.0,0.0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix ();
glFlush();
}

void init_Visualizer(void)
{
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //projection,3D-2D
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
gluOrtho2D(-640.0,640.0,-480.0,480.0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);//single buffering(?)
glutInitWindowSize(1200,540);//actual window where to be displayed
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutCreateWindow("Lab1");
init_Visualizer();
glutIdleFunc(drawRectangle);
glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: The code does not seem to match the description. I don't see any translation or reflection.